# List comprehension with two outputs

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to optimize this code:

```
num = 10
for j in xrange(0,num):
  u[j],v[j] = rk4(du,dv,t,dt,u[j],v[j])
```

where u and v are input arrays and rk4() returns two values for two input values. Using list comprehension I would do something like this:

```
u,v=[rk4(du,dv,t,dt,u[j],v[j])) for j in range(0,num)]
```

The list comprehension works. But the output is in a different format. Is it possible to optimize this kind of operation using list comprehension?

Edit: The desired output would be two arrays/lists of the form

```
u,v = [u1,u2,u3,....],[v1,v2,v3,...]
```

What I get is the of the following form:

```
[(u1,v1),(u2,v2),(u3,v3),...]
```

Comment: Please add how the outputs are different, what is your expected output

Comment: your list comprehension isn't an optimization.

Comment: Why? Actually, I've read a few blog posts suggesting to use it as some kind of performance optimization and my code is quite slow, so I am trying to do something about that.

Comment: @gumpel those blog posts are wrong. List comprehensions are only *marginally* faster than equivalent for-loops, and this advantage shrinks the more work is being done each iteration.

Comment: The main reason to prefer list comprehensions is when the code is cleaner. You can just write what goes into the list, instead of writing a command to `append` that thing to the list. The performance difference is almost certainly negligible when you're doing numerical computations (I assume [Runge-Kutta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods)).

Comment: Ok thank you. You are indeed right with Runge-Kutta. It's a reaction-diffusion system and takes quite some time.

Comment: @kaya3 Before opening a new question: Do you think it makes sense to use parallel processing for performance optimization? In particular, I call rk4 each time step for several spatial points. These calls don't depend on each other. I am just searching for any possibility to increase the speed.

Comment: If the spatial points don't depend on each other and there are a lot of time steps, then parallel processing could help, yes. The simplest way would be to write a function which produces the whole time series for a single spatial point, then do a parallel map with that function across the list of spatial points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you want to transform a sequence of pairs into two sequences. There is a standard idiom in Python to do this using the `zip` function and argument unpacking:

```py
>>> seq_of_pairs = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]
>>> u, v = zip(*seq_of_pairs)
>>> u
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
>>> v
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

So you can use a list comprehension (or generator expression) to produce the sequence of pairs using `zip`, and then use that trick to extract the two sequences:

```py
result = [ rk4(..., ui, vi) for ui, vi in zip(u, v) ]
u, v = zip(*result)
```

You can do `u, v = map(list, zip(*result))` if you need them to be lists instead of tuples.